# Vue custom looping data with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have some data that I will loop using `v-for`. But I am a little confused when I want to display data using `custom looping`, like modulus.

The result I want is data shown every `three items`, will do `grouping` so have `different class` every 3 items.

The data I want :

```
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_0">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_1">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_2">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_3">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_4">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_5">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_6">3 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_7">3 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_8">3 Blablablabla</div>
```

You see, `data_1` has 3 items. `data_2` has 3 items and `data_3` has 3 items

My Looping data :

```
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" v-for="(item, index) in this.$parent.items" :key="item._id" :content="['#data_' + index]">
    <div class="features_item sm-m-top-30">
        <div class="f_item_text">
            <img v-bind:src="item.picture">
            <span>{{ countTitle(item.title) }}</span>
            <p>{{ countSting(item.body) }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am confused when creating a modulus condition like :

```
if(i % 3 === 2)
```

How do I get every `3 recurrence data` added to class names starting from `data_1` and so on for the next 3 data

Comment: Why not divide by 3 and truncate? `1+Math.trunc(7/3)` will return 3

Comment: Hi @Botje I want to format like that... Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.floor(i/3)+1` here `i` index and start form `0`

```js
for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
  console.log(Math.floor(i/3)+1);
}
```